# How to tie a tight knot around my cable?

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I would like to tie my new connector to my cable **tightly** using the provided string.

This is what [the untied knot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coyOl.jpg) and the [the tied knot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKE36.jpg) look like; unfortunately, the adaptor can still slip and slide around the cable since the knot is loose.

- What type of topological problem is this?
- And how would it be asked mathematically?

Comment: Please make a drawing instead of photos on which I am unable to understand the issue

Comment: Practical knotting problems don't generally involve topology. A reef knot is a good knot for tying string round a parcel but a bad knot for joining two ropes together to make a longer rope (a sheet bend, a fisherman's knot or a carrick bend are much better for that). An overhand knot is a very bad stopper knot because it is hard to undo after taking a load while a figure eight knot is a great stopper knot. Topology doesn't help with physical properties of cordage that are very important in practical knotwork.

Comment: ... and in your case, it just looks like you either need a bight (loop) in the string that is to small to slip over the adaptor or an overhand knot in the cable around the string so that it can't slip. Again, no topology involved here: these are all unknots from the topological perspective.